# Android InputStream File From Assets: FileNotFoundExeption

Tags: android, string, variables, inputstream, android-assets

I'm trying to open a JSON file from the assets folder with an InputStream variable but I get FileNotFoundExeption.  The file is there and the path is correct. I've looked allover SO but anything that I have found here does not work.  Any ideas to what I have wrong and how to correct it (with code please)??

From within the calling activity:

```
String uri = "file:///android_asset/html/json/regulatory_list.json";
        args.putString("KEY_URL", uri);
```

In the Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle args = this.getArguments();
        String URL = args.getString(KEY_URL);
        new GetJSONTask().execute(URL);
    }

    class GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        String uri = arg0[0];

        InputStream is = null;

        if (uri.contains("http") == true) {// Run from URL
            try {. . .

            } else {

            try {. . .
                InputStream jsonFile = getActivity().getAssets().open(uri);
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonFile, "UTF-8"));
            . . .
        }
    . . .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your file uri is not formatted properly for what you are trying to do.

try changing this:

```
String uri = "file:///android_asset/html/json/regulatory_list.json";
```

to this:

```
String uri = "html/json/regulatory_list.json";
```

Comment: Ah!  I am enlightened. I guess .getAssets() already knows where to look. Thnx!